# Shopify nodejs app how to generate logged in url for customer?

Tags: node.js, shopify, shopify-app

We are developing Shopify app for social login, we get accessTocken then we try to  create customer from our app and it works fine  and now we need to generate logged in url after created user account in Shopify.How to do that?